# Retrieve data from Network preview/response Mapbox-gl

Tags: reactjs, mapbox

I'm building an App with Mapbox-gl and mapbox-gl-directions with React.js. The code is quite simple and it works perfectly. However I need to retrieve the data corresponding to the Km in order to calculate costs per km.

I see the data in the dev tools under the Network tab - Preview. So my question is, how can I retrieve that data? I cannot find any information online...

This is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
import MapboxDirections from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/dist/mapbox-gl-directions';
import '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/dist/mapbox-gl-directions.css'

mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_KEY

class App extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleDirections()
    
  }

  handleDirections() {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: this.mapWrapper,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
      center: [-73.985664, 40.748514],
      zoom: 12
    })

    const directions = new MapboxDirections({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      unit: 'metric',
      profile: 'mapbox/driving',
      annotations: 'distance'
    })

    map.addControl(directions, 'top-left');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        ref={el => (this.mapWrapper = el)}
        className='mapWrapper'
      />
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

I'm quite new and I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible or not.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution by subscribing to the event adding:

```js
directions.on('route', (route) => {
      console.log(route.route[0].distance)
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this can help someone in similar situation.